# PHP Mysql query that gets a timeframe of all mondays within a certain date range and puts those different start and end times in a database

Tags: php, mysql, date, for-loop

I have a challenge where I want all the start and end epoch of all the certain days (example Monday) within a specific date range and put these in individual rows
The table looks like this:

```
+----+---------+------------+------------+
| id | id_room | start_ts   | end_ts     |
| 3  | 3       | 1445032800 | 1445378400 |
| 4  | 3       | 1445551200 | 1446073200 |
| 5  | 3       | 1446246000 | 1446591600 |
| 6  | 3       | 1446850800 | 1447196400 |
| 7  | 3       | 1447455600 | 1447801200 |
| 8  | 3       | 1448060400 | 1448406000 |
| 9  | 2       | 1445475600 | 1445572800 |
| 10 | 1       | 1445378400 | 1445464800 |
| 11 | 3       | 1445032800 | 1445378400 |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
```

I manage to get the start and end epochs in a few different ways:

```
$start = strtotime('2016-06-01');
$end = strtotime('2016-06-30');

$mondays_start=array();

while( $start <= $end  ) {
  if ( date('N',$start)== 1 )   
    $mondays_start[]=$start+43200;

  $start += 86400; 
}

$start = strtotime('2016-06-01');
$end = strtotime('2016-06-30');
$mondays_end=array();

while( $start <= $end  ) {
  if ( date('N',$start)== 1 )   
    $mondays_end[]=$start+64800;

  $start += 86400; 

}
```

But my real problem starts when I try to get them into my table. I guess I can break the arrays up into different variables and make individual queries based on that but it doesn't seem very productive.

I tried some of the solution here [Is it bad to put a MySQL query in a PHP loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733023/is-it-bad-to-put-a-mysql-query-in-a-php-loop) but cannot get it to work.

I also tried it in a for loop like so

```
$start = strtotime('2016-06-01');
$end = strtotime('2016-06-30');
for ($start; $start < $end; $start+604800) {
$mondays .= "INSERT INTO `#__room_closure`(`id_room`,`start_ts`,`end_ts`) VALUES( ".
        $args['id_room'].",".$start.",".$start+21600.");";
}
```

But that doesnt work either.

Looking forward to your thoughts on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a way to answer the question however it creates a new one.

The answer is as follows:

```
for ($args["start_ts"]; $args["start_ts"] < $args["end_ts"]; $args["start_ts"]+=604800) {
$mondays .= "INSERT INTO `#__room_closure`(`id_room`,`start_ts`,`end_ts`) VALUES( ".
        $args['id_room'].",".$args["start_ts"].",".($args["start_ts"]+21600).");";
};
```

this will create an array with the several different queries in a string:

```
"INSERT INTO `#__room_closure`(`id_room`,`start_ts`,`end_ts`) VALUES( 1,1306900800,1306922400);INSERT INTO `#__room_closure`(`id_room`,`start_ts`,`end_ts`) VALUES( 1,1307505600,1307527200);INSERT INTO `#__room_closure`(`id_room`,`start_ts`,`end_ts`) VALUES( 1,1308110400,1308132000);INSERT INTO `#__room_closure`(`id_room`,`start_ts`,`end_ts`) VALUES( 1,1308715200,1308736800);INSERT INTO `#__room_closure`(`id_room`,`start_ts`,`end_ts`) VALUES( 1,1309320000,1309341600);"
```

This solved my question.

However with joomla I cannot put multiple queries in the Query() function. But that is a different story and should be told another time.